# Rails - Query has_many Association without Duplicating Myself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

We have 3 models in our application: Trips, Destinations, and CountryReferences (reference table).

Our associations description is as follows:

- A **Trip** has_many **Destinations**
- A **Destination** has_one **CountryReference**
- A **Trip** has_many **CountryReferences** through **Destinations**

The CountryReference table is a reference that maps each country to a region and sub region using the ISO_2 code as key. For example, Thailand would have a region of Asia and a sub region of South-east Asia. All the association are tested and working properly. Each Trip also has a column 'Views'.

**The Goal**

We are trying to create a method that returns an array with the the 6 most popular (# of views) trips in each region. We want to avoid duplicating a trip, that is, if a trip spans multiple regions, we only want to add it to the array once.

**Our Code**

```
 #returns a an array of trips, this array should contain at least 'num_per_region' trips per region
  def self.popular_by_region(num_per_region)
    regions = []
    regions.push 'Asia'
    regions.push 'Europe'
    regions.push 'Africa'
    regions.push 'Central America and the Caribbean'
    regions.push 'South America'
    regions.push 'Australia and Oceania'
    regions.push 'North America'

    trips_array = []
    trips_hash = {} #used to figure out if trip has already been added to array

    #load 6 most popular trips per region
    regions.each do |region|
      region_trips = Trip.joins(:country_references).where('country_references.region' => region, 'published' => true).order(views: :desc).limit(num_per_region*3)
      region_trips.each do |trip|
        if trips_hash[trip.id].nil?
          trips_hash[trip.id] = 1
          trips_array.push trip
        end
      end
    end

    return trips_array

  end
```

**The Problem**

The ActiveRecord query `Trip.join...` returns once trip per destination. That is, if my trip has 5 destinations, all in Asia, then that same trip will be returned 5 times. How can we adjust this query so that each trip is only returned once?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this.

```
Trip.joins(:country_references).where('country_references.region' => region, 'published' => true).group('trips.id').order(views: :desc).limit(num_per_region*3)
```